# Divide a sparse matrix into train and test

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

Hi i have a sparse csr matrix built in this way:

```
userid = list(np.sort(matrix.USERID.unique()))  # Get our unique customers
artid = list(matrix.ARTID.unique())  # Get our unique products that were purchased
click = list(matrix.TOTALCLICK)

rows = pd.Categorical(matrix.USERID, categories=userid).codes

# Get the associated row indices
cols = pd.Categorical(matrix.ARTID, categories=artid).codes

# Get the associated column indices
item_sparse = sparse.csr_matrix((click, (rows, cols)), shape=(len(userid), len(artid)))
```

The original `matrix` contains user interaction with product on a website.

I end up with a sparse matrix in this format

```
  (0, 4136) 1
  (0, 5553) 1
  (0, 9089) 1
  (0, 24104) 3
  (0, 28061) 2
  (1, 0)    2
  (1, 224)  1
  (1, 226)  1
  (1, 324)  2
  (1, 341)  1
  (1, 530)  1
  (1, 642)  1
  (1, 658)  1
```

How can I group by this sparse matrix by first index ( users) and take say the first 80% of rows for training set and the other 20% for test set. I should end up with two matrix

training:

```
  (0, 4136) 1
  (0, 5553) 1
  (0, 9089) 1
  (1, 0)    2
  (1, 224)  1
  (1, 226)  1
  (1, 324)  2
  (1, 341)  1
  (1, 530)  1
```

test:

```
  (0, 24104)    3
  (0, 28061)    2
  (1, 642)      1
  (1, 658)      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `StratifiedShuffleSplit` (or alternatively `StratifiedKFold` if you don't want shuffling, but you would need to do 5 splits to get an 80%/20% train/test split, as you can't control the test size in other ways.) class in scikit-learn:

```
import sklearn.model_selection
import numpy as np

# Array similar to your structure
x = np.asarray([[0,4136,1],[0,5553,1],[0,9089,1],[1,0,2], \
                [1,224,1],[1,226,1],[1,324,2],[1,341,1],[1,530,1]])
# Get train and test indices using x[:,0] to define the 'classes'
cv = sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2)
# Note, X isn't actually used in the method, np.zeros(n_samples) would also work
# Also note that cv.split is an iterator with 1 element (split), 
# hence getting the first element of the list
train_idx, test_idx = list(cv.split(X=x, y=x[:,0]))[0]

print("Training")
for i in train_idx:
    print(x[i,:2], x[i,2])
print("Test")
for i in test_idx: 
    print(x[i,:2], x[i,2])
```

I don't have much experience with sparse matrices, so I hope that you can make the necessary adjustments from my example.

Comment: You're converting the sparse matrix to a dense one if someone is using a sparse matrix is because of memory limitations. I don't feel like this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

use sklearn api train_test_split you will gave the this method 3 parameters your matrix the ratio of splitting and the random state. random state is very useful if you want to split again with the same result.